# How to fix this error in my code. "The type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader' has no constructors defined"

Tags: c#, find

I have create database. There is a field as a IMEI. 
I tried to suggest data in combo-box as a drop down list. But i failed. Please help me to correct this code. How will i fix this error.

```
Private void Autocomplete()  
    {  
        OleDbConnection con = new 
        OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|/Neth1.accdb");  
        con.Open();  
        string sql = "SELECT IMEI FROM Products";  
        OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);  
        OleDbDataReader reader = new OleDbDataReader();  
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();  
        AutoCompleteStringCollection autocomp = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();  
        while (reader.Read())  
        {  
            comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;  
            comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;  
            comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autocomp;  
        }  
        reader.Close();  
        con.Close();  

    }
```

Comment: There's no need to initialize `OleDbDataReader` with default constructor, you can use it directly: `OleDbDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();`.

Answer (score 0):

[OldDbDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) does not have any public constructors so you cannot construct it like that. Just do this:

```
OldDbDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
```